# Как обновить данные в спиннере которые добавляются с помощью диалога?

Tags: java, android, update, android-spinner

Есть:

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directories);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);
            mDirect.setName_directory(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
```

и есть:

```
mEditDirectory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View editView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.editactivity, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            mDialogBuilder.setView(editView);
            final EditText userInput = (EditText) editView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
            mDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mDatabaseDirectory = new DirectBaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    if (userInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Категория не создана", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        values.put(DirectoryTable.Colums.NAMEDIR, userInput.getText().toString());
                        mDatabaseDirectory.insert(DirectoryTable.DIRECTORY_NAME, null, values);

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Новая категория создана",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

Подскажите как обновить адаптер, знаю что c помощью `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` но куда его засунуть чтобы работал, после добавления записи в диалоге. Думал в диалог, но нет, в `onResume()`, тоже нет...

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы произвести действия после закрытия диалога, используйте интерфейс [`DialogInterface.OnDismssListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnDismissListener?hl=ru).

Имплементируете этот интерфейс и реализуете его метод `onDismiss()` - данный колбэк будет вызван, когда диалоговое окно будет закрыто. В вашем случае тут вы можете вызвать обновление адаптера.